# Sleeping and invoking a task in Python 2.X and Python 3.X

Tags: python, iterator, reflection, variadic

I'm writing a program that needs to be compatible for both Python 2.X and Python 3.X. My problem is that, because of the differences between these two versions, I'm duplicating code.

```
try:
        ### Python 2.X part
        time.sleep(iterator.next())
        if len(arguments) >= len(inspect.getargspec(task).args):
            task(*arguments)
        else:
            print("ERROR: There is a mismatch between the number of"
                  " arguments provided in `arguments` and the ones"
                  " needed by the task function.")
except AttributeError:
        ### Python 3.X part
        time.sleep(next(iterator))
        if len(arguments) >= len(inspect.getfullargspec(task).args):
            task(*arguments)
        else:
            print("ERROR: There is a mismatch between the number of"
                  " arguments provided in `arguments` and the ones"
                  " needed by the task function.")
```

It can be seen that both versions only differ in the usage of `next()`, `inspect.getargspec()` and `inspect.getfullargspec()`, while the other logic remains the same. Is there any way to optimize the execution of the tasks, in `tasks(*arguments)`, and the printing of the error messages, so that I don't have to repeat the same code? This is just sample working code, but I mean my question in a more broader and general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `next()` function in both Python 2.6+ and 3.x. If you need to support Python < 2.6, you can have [your own `next()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11652442/771848). You can, for instance, check if referring to `next` throws a `NameError` and define it if it does:

```
try:
    next
except NameError:
    _sentinel = object()
    def next(it, default=_sentinel):
        try:
            return it.next()
        except StopIteration:
            if default is _sentinel:
                raise
            return default
```

Even though `getargspec()` got *deprecated since 3.0,* it still can be used and imported. In this case, you can import `getfullargspec()` and catch the `ImportError`:

```
try:
    from inspect import getfullargspec as get_args  # Python 3
except ImportError:
    from inspect import getargspec as get_args  # Python 2
```

Taking these both points into account, the code would look like:

```
time.sleep(next(iterator))
if len(arguments) >= len(get_args(task).args):
    task(*arguments)
else:
    print("ERROR: There is a mismatch between the number of"
          " arguments provided in `arguments` and the ones"
          " needed by the task function.")
```

As far as generally supporting multiple Python versions in a single codebase, [`six`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) is a must use package.

---

Also note that instead of using `inspect` to pre-validate the number of arguments, you can follow the [`EAFP` approach](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp), call the function and handle a `TypeError`:

```
>>> f = lambda x, y: 'test'
>>> f(1,2,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. It was the first time I heard about the EAFP approach.